# How to get web matrix node.js starter template on non-microsoft os

Tags: webmatrix

I've been using web matrix for node.js for quite some time now.  I love the starter template and how it frees us to get to start on coding asap. unfortunately, i had to shift to a non-microsoft OS, so i was wondering if the started template could be downloaded from somewhere not via webmatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - I keep this template up to date on our GitHub:
https://github.com/MicrosoftWebMatrix/ExpressStarter

Happy Coding!